# Save a view with images to edit later in iOS

Tags: ios

I have a view which has images, this images are added by the user, once the user decide the image to add, the user drag the image to a specific position in the screen, the number of images is completely dynamic.

What I want is to save in a file, an array or whatever you suggest the view with the images for lately the user could edit the images or positions.

I'm not asking for code I just want a hint for accomplish what I need. What do you think is the best way to archive this?

Thank you all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to exit the app use `NSUserDefaults` to save it and use later.

If you are not going to exit you can set a global `NSMutableArray` and add the `UIImageViews` for later use.

Comment: Thanks Arbitur I'll do some tests and if ok, right answer!

Comment: @TonyM. did my anwser help you?

Comment: I'm working on it @Arbitur, I'll let you know when I have an answer :). BTW Do you know if I could store the NSMutableArray into a file?

Comment: You use NSDictionary for that and save it in a property list (.plist), but NSUserDefault is almost exactly the same as save it to a file. Unless you want to export the file to use somewhere else.